# Entire background including image is animating in Kivy. How do i animate only the image?

Tags: animation, kivy

I am trying to animate a image just to a certain area of the screen.

**start_screen.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.window import Window
import time

def set_color(button, color, *args):
    button.color = color

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class StartScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StartScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def reset_color(*args):
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(set_color,
              self.ids.pstart_button,
              (1,1,1,1)), 1)
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(set_color,
              self.ids.pstart_button,
              (0,1,0,1)), 2)
        Clock.schedule_interval(reset_color, 3)

    #def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        #if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            #self.to_menu()

    def to_menu(self):
        sb=self.ids.pstart_button
        anim = Animation(pos =(Window.width * .05, Window.height *.60))
        anim &= Animation(size =(Window.width * .15, Window.height * .15))
        anim.start(sb)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return StartScreen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.9
<StartScreen>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size: root.size
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bg.png'

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        ImageButton:
            id: pstart_button
            size_hint: (.30,.30)
            pos: root.center_x - (self.width/2), root.center_y - (self.height/2)
            source: 'start_button.png'
            on_touch_down: if pstart_button.collide_point(pstart_button.x, pstart_button.y): root.to_menu()

<MenuScreen>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size: root.size
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bg2.png'

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        ImageButton:
            id: start_button
            size_hint: ( .15,  .15)
            pos:  root.width * .05, root.height *.60
            source: 'start_button.png'


        ImageButton:
            id:usb_button
            size_hint: (None, None)
            width: start_button.width * .80
            height: start_button.height * .80
            x: start_button.width *.75
            y: start_button.y - (start_button.height * .99)
            source: r'usb_button.png'

        ImageButton:
            id:remote_button
            size_hint: (None, None)
            width: start_button.width * .80
            height: start_button.height * .80
            x: start_button.width *.75
            y: usb_button.y - (start_button.height * .99)
            source: r'remote_button.png'

        ImageButton:
            id:sdcard_button
            size_hint: (None, None)
            width: start_button.width * .80
            height: start_button.height * .80
            x: start_button.width *.75
            y: remote_button.y - (start_button.height * .99)
            source: r'sdcard_button.png'

        ImageButton:
            id:home_button
            size_hint: ( .1,.1)
            pos: root.width * .73, root.height *.88
            source: 'home_button.png'

        ImageButton:
            id:settings_button
            size_hint: ( .1,  .1)
            pos: home_button.x +(home_button.width * .89), root.height * .88
            source: 'settings_button.png'

        ImageButton:
            id:back_button
            size_hint: ( .1,  .1)
            pos: settings_button.x +(settings_button.width * .89), root.height * .88
            source: 'back_button.png'
```

The issue is when i try to animate and use "self" it ends up animating my background along with the widget. I just want the widget animated. I think i am sure why self moves the whole thing because self is the entire widget layout. My code shows where i just tried to animate the widget but it did not work.

Also the collide point does not seem to be working as well. If i click anywhere on the screen it would animate. I have a feeling if I can just get the image to move then it might solve this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to separate functionality. I was trying to animate the widget from in the Main Layout. What i should have been doing is placing the functionality of the widget (and any widget for that matter) in its own class. Rookie mistake. I moved to_menu() to my ImageButtton class and it worked. Also the collide point worked as well when i moved behaviour to the button.